# How to implement user input in a linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list

For this code I need to be able to use user input of books they have read and put them in a linked list. I have most of the code done but when I try putting books in the list the code isn't adding the books to the list. How can I fix this?
this is the function.cpp file

```
void displayMenu()
{
  cout << "[1]  Add Book\n"
       << "[2]  Size Of List\n"
       << "[3]  Display List\n"
       << "[4]  Remove Last Book\n"
       << "[5]  Delete List\n"
       << "[6]  Quit Program\n"
       << "Enter Choice:  ";
}
int getChoice(int & choice1)
{
  cin >> choice1;   
    while (choice1 < 1 || choice1 > 6) {
      cout << endl;
      cout << "Invalid Entry!!" << endl;
      cout << "Enter Choice:  ";
      cin >> choice1; 
    }
  return choice1;
}
int endProgram(bool & start2)
{
  start2 = false;
  cout << "\n\n\t\tThank you for using this system!!\n\n";
  return start2;
}

void clear()
{
  system("clear");
}

void linkedList::addBook()
{
  Book *ptr;
  bool quit = false;
  string temp = "";
  while (!quit)
    {
      cout << "Enter a book(enter quit to stop): ";
      cin >> temp;

      if (temp == "quit")
      {
        quit = true;
        return;
      }
      ptr = new Book;
      ptr->data = temp;
      ptr->next = NULL;
      if(head == NULL)
      {
        head = ptr;
        tail = ptr;
      }
      else
      {
        tail->next = ptr;
        tail = tail->next;
      }
    }
  return;
}

void linkedList::displayList()
{
  Book *ptr;
  ptr = head;
  while (ptr != NULL)
  {
    cout << ptr->data << endl;
    ptr = ptr->next;
  }
}

void linkedList::listSize()
{
  Book *ptr;
  int counter = 0;
  ptr = head;
  while (ptr != NULL)
  {
    ptr = ptr->next;
    counter++;
  }
  cout << "Number of books in the list: " << counter;
}

void linkedList::deleteLast()
{
  if (head == NULL)
    return;
  if (head->next == NULL) 
  {
    delete head;
    head = NULL;
    return;
  }
  // Find the second last node
  Book* ptr = head;
  while (ptr->next->next != NULL)
    ptr = ptr->next;
  // Delete last node
  delete (ptr->next);
  // Change next of second last
  ptr->next = NULL;
  if(ptr == NULL)
    cout << "Last book is cleared!" << endl;
}

void linkedList::deleteList()
{
  Book *ptr;
  while (head != NULL)
  {
    ptr = head->next;
    delete head;
    head = ptr;
  }
 
  if(head == NULL)
  cout <<"List is cleared!" << endl; 
}
```

This is the main.cpp file

```
int main() {
  int choice = 0;
  bool start = true;
  linkedList a;
  while(start != false)
  {
    while(choice != 6)
    {
      displayMenu();
      getChoice(choice);
      if(choice == 1)
      {
        clear();
        a.addBook();
      }
      if(choice == 2)
      {
        clear();
        a.listSize();
      }
      if(choice == 3)
      {
        clear();
        a.displayList();
        cout << endl;
      } 
      if(choice == 4)
      {
        clear();
        a.deleteLast();
      }
      if(choice == 5)
      {
        clear();
        a.deleteList();
      }
      if(choice == 6)
      {
        clear();
        endProgram(start);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Last is the function.h file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Book
{
  string data;
  Book *next;
};

class linkedList
{
private:
    Book *head,*tail;
public:
  linkedList()
  {
      head = NULL;
      tail = NULL;
  }
  void addBook();
  void displayList();
  void listSize();
  void deleteList();
  void deleteLast();
};

void displayMenu();
int getChoice(int & choice1);
int endProgram(bool & start2);
void clear();
```

Comment: You don't. You implement a linked list. You test the snot out of it so that you know it works. Then you implement a user of the linked list that gets inputs and placed them into the linked list. Try to do both at the same time and you're increase your development time greatly. In general separate responsibilities as much as possible. In a perfect world every thing does one thing (and does it well).

Comment: Note: `void linkedList::deleteLast()` should not return anything. yet the coed in the function DOES return a node. You need to change the return type.

Comment: Typo here: `head == ptr;` This is a comparison, not an assignment. Recommendation: Stop writing new code. Fix what you have, then add more functionality. In general, write a few lines. compile. Test until you are satisfied that the code works. Then write a few more lines. If you write lots of code at once you are almost certainly writing lot of bugs, and you will have to untangle those bugs before you can solve them. Debugging code almost always take s longer than writing code, so if you slow down the writing to minimize the number of bugs you have to deal with, you profit in the long run.

Comment: It's not uncommon to write a lot of code and then find an early bug that forces you to rethink the whole program and throw out the bulk of what you wrote after that the code with the bug.

Comment: How can I continue to add to the linked list. The code right now is functional enough to add books to it but once the code runs once and you add a few books you can't add anymore. Why is this?

Comment: Because there is  a bug. It's not worth adding new features until the bug is resolved because you'll be making the bug-hunting even harder. At this point you should back up the code and start removing features until you can isolate the bug. The less code you have, the fewer places for the bug to hide. Use [mre] for inspiration.

Comment: just to be clear - you are not allowed to use `std::list` right?

Comment: There is no bug right now it all runs fine I think it's just a problem with how the addBook() function is written.

Comment: Can't use that no.

Comment: I add a book in you program ok and it gets added to the list 'quit' gets added too but thats probably a simple fix. Whats you actual problem

Comment: Yes I fixed that by adding return in the if statement so that it wouldn't add quit. The actual problem is once you add one book then quit you can't add anymore books.

Comment: also if you delete the last book after adding it you cannot get size of display the list

Comment: I can add a book, quit, then add a second book fine, no repro

Comment: My bad the error is when you remove a book the code is stuck you can't add a book after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK got it

In deleteLast

```
if (head->next == NULL)
{
    delete head;
    return;
}
```

You forgot to update head

```
if (head->next == NULL)
{
    delete head;
    head = NULL; <<<<=====
    return;
}
```

also in the delete function you don't update tail, you need

```
Book* ptr = head;
while (ptr->next->next != NULL)
    ptr = ptr->next;
// Delete last node
delete (ptr->next);
tail = ptr;<<<<<<<<<<<===================
// Change next of second last
ptr->next = NULL;
```

You really need to learn to use your debugger

Comment: This seemed promising and is a good fix but the code still doesn't allow you to add a book after deleting the last.

Comment: @coolcat doent crash after delet tho

Comment: @coolcat - works for me, add, delete, add. Alos works, add,add,delete,delete, add

Comment: right now it only works when it clears so that there are no books in the list. So like if you did add, add, delete, delete, add. that's if there is still on book left on the list then it won't work.

Comment: So like if you did add, add, delete, add it wouldn't work.

Comment: @coolcat - ok i fixed the adding of quit, I put that bug back in an now it fails

Comment: to fix the adding of quit all you have to do is add return.

Comment: if (temp == "quit")
      {
        quit = true;
        return;
      }